# Exchange secret key without trusting my own server

Tags: algorithm, security, key

How can I exchange a secret key without using public keys avoiding the necessity of having to verify the key with a CA?

I want to use SSL/TLS to comunicate with my server. But I do want to cipher the content. For this I need to distribute a key among the peers but I dont want to trust my own server or a public key from a peer(avoid the CA verification because I dont want to trust the CA).

Impossible?
Do I need to trust somebody? xD

Any ideia? Algorithm?

Comment: What do you mean, without using public keys? You need to trust *someone* in this process. Who will exchange this key, a client and  your own server?

Comment: I want to exchange a key between clients of that server.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You need to trust someone in the process to ensure you are not talking to the wrong person. This means that you either do all communication through this entity (i.e. your server), or the entity acts as a CA to authenticate other parties.

Comment: To exchange keys, you will need to use asymmetric encryption. This means that the two entities that exchange the secret key will both have their own pair of (private, public) keys. You will obviously need to trust someone with their public key, otherwise there is no possible exchange ... And the entity you trust will have to trust you as well !

Comment: That was my thought too. Just wanted to know if I could do something else. But now how can a client verify the pub key of other clients?

Comment: Once I dont want to trust my own server and I dont want to force my clients to get a valid certificate(not a self signed one). Impossible too or we can have something else?

Comment: A client *must* use a CA of some kind (which can be your server) to verify the public key of another client. It boils down to this, even if you choose to implement it in a custom way different from standard TLS (which is, btw, not a good idea since TLS has been designed by security professionals, already thoroughly tested, and you can only make your app [weaker by designing your own protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)). But if clients are preconfigured to have a hardcoded public key of your server, then your server is basically a trusted CA.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming and should be asked on http://crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Can I transfer this to crypto fast? How?